# Hide UIButton added in UITabBarController from child ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBar application, which I have added a UIButton too, which brings up a menu.

This is how the menu button is added to the Tab Controller:

```
//TabBarViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(285, 28, 24, 24);
    [menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.menuBtn];
}
```

This functions fine and produces the following:

[image: The button is visible and working in the top right corner.]

*I have the button in the Tab Bar Controller so it shows on each tab.*

This all works fine, but when I use the search bar the menu button becomes in the way:

[image: Button is now covering the cancel button.]

### **How would I be able to hide the menu button while the search is active?**

I have worked out how to detect when the search bar is active, but I am having trouble trying to hide the menu button.

```
//SearchViewController.m

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    TabBarViewController *vc = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
    [vc.menuBtn setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {   
    TabBarViewController *vc = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
    [vc.menuBtn setHidden:NO];
}
```

I have tried a few methods, but nothing is able to hide the menu button. Is this impossible, or am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you need to get a reference to the tab bar controller that you already have, not create a new one with alloc init. I can't tell you how to do that without knowing more about the app's structure. What is that bar where you added the button? What controllers do you have? Is the TabBarViewController the initial view controller?

Comment: @rdelmar I understand what you mean, makes sense. But still not sure how to create a reference. The TabBarViewController is not the initial view controller, I have a UIViewController as init (which is where the menuBtn connects to).
The structure is like this:
`MenuViewController(UIViewController)` => `TabBarViewController(UITabBarController)` => `SearchNavigationController(UINavigationController)` => `SearchViewController(UITableViewController)` So the `menuBtn` is in the `TabBarViewController` and I need to hide it from the `SearchViewController`

Comment: So what is the bar that you added the button to? Is this the navigation bar for the SearchNavigationController, or did you add a navigation bar to the tab bar controller itself?

Comment: The button is added to the `TabBarViewController` which is the tab bar controller itself, the TabBarViewController does not have a navigation controller.

Comment: how i hide tablview when parent view controller tab bar button click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **rdelmar** commented:

> you need to get a reference to the tab bar controller that you already have, not create a new one with alloc init.

Currently I was making a new TabBarViewController, with this:

```
TabBarViewController *vc = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
```

Instead, I needed to use a reference. I was able to do this by using 'parentViewController'.

The structure of the app from the TabBarViewController is:

1. TabBarViewController
2. SearchNavigationController
3. SearchViewController

So by using 'parentViewController' twice I was able to reference TabBarViewController, then hide the menuBtn.

The following is what worked for me:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    ((TabBarViewController *)self.parentViewController.parentViewController).menuBtn.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    ((TabBarViewController *)self.parentViewController.parentViewController).menuBtn.hidden = NO;
}
```